# is there a way to skip "Press any Key to continue" in windows ssh when connection is closed by remote host?

Tags: batch-file, autoit, openssh

I have a script to automate upgrading some IoT devices via autoit and a .bat file. I want to be able to skip the "press any key to continue" prompt that shows up with the device closes is shell session.

I've got the ssh command set up to login to device without password and without keycheck to run the shell command. I'v attempted to get autoit to watch the console with no luck, set the ssh command to batch mode, and had autoit send an enter press to the console every couple of seconds (last one kind of worked but caused different problems.)

```sh
ssh [user]@[host] -q -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "[command parameters]"
```

I'd like to either have ssh suppress "press any key" response, have the batch file or autoit continue the script after connection closed, or any other way that I can get the .bat file to continue after this prompt without require human interaction.

Comment: maybe just get stdin from nul? `command<nul`

Comment: Do you get `press any key` for any command? I can't reproduce your behaviour on Win10 with OpenSSH

Comment: no its coming up when the system you have ssh'd into closes the connection while using the ssh.exe from openssh. You can most likely reproduce by sending a reboot command through ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I never saw the text `press any key to continue` from ssh, but grep shows that it's really included in the ssh.exe (C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe).

You could try to use the ssh from git-bash, there shouldn't be such a problem.

At least a test would show if that's the problem or perhaps the text comes from your device.

Comment: Can confirm that its in issue with the ssh.exe. Problem is this needs to be fully self contained in a folder (had to pus ssh.exe and scp.exe into my autoit launch folder) so that I don't have to use full file paths (as this could cause it to break when moved to a different computer).